# Multiple OnClick associated to WebViews inside loop

Tags: java, android, button, webview

I want to link my `Button`s to the associated `WebView`s. I have 2 lists, one of `Button` the other one of `WebViews`. What I'm trying to do is, showing or hiding the `webView[x]` associated to `button[x]`

```
    nbObjects = 2;
    Button[] buttons = null;
    buttons = new Button[nbObjects];
    buttons[0] = findViewById(R.id.button0);
    buttons[1] = findViewById(R.id.button1);

    WeView[] webViews = null;
    webViews = new WebView[nbObjects];
    webViews[0] = findViewById(R.id.webView0);
    webViews[1] = findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    for (int i = 0; i < nbObjects; i++) {
        webViews[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        final int j = i;
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (webViews[j].getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    webViews[j].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    webViews[j].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Result: when I click on `Button0`, everything works. `WebView0` shows and hides. But not for `WebView1` when I click on `Button1`.

***Solution/Update***

My `WebView`s are actually showing up. I added a background color to spot them when no URL was loaded. Now time to loadURL